# Methods for an interface with a variable number of parameters

Tags: java, interface

I'd like to ask you if it's possible in Java to have a declaration of a method in a interface but, I want that the methods defined could have a variable number of input parameters (for example, all of the same type). I was thinking in something like this:

```
public interface EqualsCriteria {

    public boolean isEqual(String... paramsToCheck); 
    // this is not equals(Object obj) !!!

}
```

And one class implements that equal criteria like, for example:

```
public class CommonEquals implements EqualsCriteria {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    ....
    @Override
    public boolean isEqual(String otherName, String otherSurname) {
        return name.equals(otherName) && surname.equals(otherSurname);
    }

}
```

But maybe, I want other criteria in another part of the code, something like this

```
public class SpecialEquals implements EqualsCriteria {
    ....
    @Override
    public boolean isEqual(String otherName, String otherSurname, String passport) {
        return name.equals(otherName) && surname.equals(otherSurname) && passport.equals(passport);
    }

}
```

PS: Actually my problem is a little bit more complicated, but this could be useful to me.

Comment: why not trying and seeing it yourself?

Comment: A given implementation of the String ... form can look at the actual number of arguments, and call other methods based on that.

Comment: If you want a variable amount of parameters all of the same type, just use an array.

Comment: i think no..but an alternative would be `public boolean isEqual(String[] paramsToCheck);`

Comment: Because you are trying to change the interface defn

Comment: This interface is not required it's only confuses the programmers.

Comment: I hope I'm not wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be:

```
public interface EqualsCriteria {
    public boolean isEqual(EqualsCriteria other); 
    public String[] getParam();
    // this is not equals(Object obj) !!!
}
```

And then:

```
public class CommonEquals implements EqualsCriteria {
    private String name;
    private String surname;


    @Override
    public boolean isEqual(EqualsCriteria other) {
     if(other==null) return false;
     return Arrays.asList(getParam()).equals(Arrays.asList(other.getParam()));
    }

    }
```

This way, even if number of Strings changes, still it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by checking size of the array

```
public class CommonEquals implements EqualsCriteria {
private String name;
private String surname;

....
@Override
public boolean isEqual(String .. arr) {
    if (arr.length != 2) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();  // or return false
    }
    return name.equals(arr[0]) && surname.equals(arr[1]);
}
}
```

**EDIT**

The only way you can do this to have it more readable (extract common part)

```
@Override
public boolean isEqual(String oName, String oSurname, String .. arr) {
    return name.equals(oName) && surname.equals(oSurname); //ignore arr since you don't need it
}
```

And for the other class you'll have

```
@Override
public boolean isEqual(String otherName, String otherSurname, String .. arr) {
    return name.equals(otherName) && surname.equals(otherSurname) && passport.equals(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution. But for being more readable I would like to use the explicit declaration of the parameters you are going to check, name, surname, passport, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> public interface EqualsCriteria {
>
> public boolean isEqual(ArrayList parameter);
>
> }

in resume you can not modify, the quantity of parameters of function, because is not an override.